# Overriding a plexus component declared in another plugin

Tags: maven-3, maven-release-plugin, plexus

I'm currently writing a Maven plugin with automates releasing of modules by

- detecting if a module has changes which should be released
- releasing all modules using the `maven-release-plugin`
- adjusting dependencies in all affected projects

I'm trying to test it using the `maven-invoker-plugin`, which uses the following setup in the integration-test poms:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>@project.groupId@</groupId>
        <artifactId>@project.artifactId@</artifactId>
        <version>@project.version@</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>my-id</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>my-goal</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The roadblock I'm hitting is that the `maven-dependency-plugin` forbids this release since I reference a SNAPSHOT plugin in my pom.xml ( the `@project.version@` above ). Fair enough.

I discovered that this check is made in [CheckDependencySnapshotsPhase](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/release/tags/maven-release-2.4.1/maven-release-manager/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/shared/release/phase/CheckDependencySnapshotsPhase.java?view=markup) , which is a plexus component:

> @plexus.component role="org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ReleasePhase" role-hint="check-dependency-snapshots"

Can I somehow override this component and plug in my own? Alternatively, how can I run this integration test without being blocked by the 'no snapshot depenendencies' check?

Comment: Sound very interesting. Is this plugin open source? I would be interested in it.

Comment: Not yet, and I can't make promises about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was right in front of me. Instead of configuring the plugin in the IT project pom.xml, just instruct the `maven-invoker-plugin` to execute it ( abridged ):

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}:inspect-changes</goal>
          </goals>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```